# json data not displaying in jqgrid formate in asp.mvc

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

When I run view it shows only in JSON format like this

{"total":1,"page":1,"records":4,"rows":[{"id":2,"cell":["fsff      ","fsfs      ","2"]},{"id":3,"cell":["fsff      ","fsfs45    ","3"]},{"id":5,"cell":["shah      ","krutika   ","5"]},{"id":6,"cell":["1235      ","krutik    ","6"]}]}

My code behind like this:
View:

```
<html>
<head>

    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.2.0.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.4.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.jqGrid.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/i18n/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
    <link href="~/Content/jquery.jqGrid/ui.jqgrid.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/Content/themes/base/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function myfunction() {

        $('#list').jqGrid({
            caption: "Employee Details",
            url: '/Default1/grid/',
            datatype: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset-utf-8",
            mtype: 'GET',
            colNames: ['Address', 'Name'],
            colModel: [
                  { name: 'address', index: 'address', width: 150 },

                  { name: 'name', index: 'name', width: 150 }
            ],
            pager: "#pager",
            rowNum: 10,
            rowList: [10, 20, 30],
            sortname: "invid",
            sortorder: "desc",
            viewrecords: true,
            gridview: true,
            autoencode: true,
            caption: "My first grid"
        });

        jQuery("#list").jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager', { edit: true, add: true, del: true });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <table id="list"><tr><td></td></tr></table>
    <div id="pager"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

And in controller:

```
public JsonResult grid()
            {
                employeeDBEntities entity= new employeeDBEntities();
                emp e1=new emp();
                var jsondata=new{
                    total=1,
                    page=1,
                    records=entity.emps.ToList().Count,
                   rows = (  
               from emp in entity.emps.ToList()
              select new  
              {
                  id = emp.id,  
                 cell = new string[] {   
                   emp.address.ToString(), emp.name.ToString(),emp.id.ToString()
                }  
             }).ToArray()  
         };
                return Json(jsondata,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Always load css first because js files use those css

.Here is the order it should be.

```
    <link href="~/Content/themes/base/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/> 
    <link href="~/Content/jquery.jqGrid/ui.jqgrid.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.2.0.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.4.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.jqGrid.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/i18n/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
```